# Swift Create Categories for Items (Classes + Attributes) at runtime

Tags: swift, class, object, runtime

I have a problem I am not able to figure out myself or find any answer to:

I am creating an inventar app for my company and I want that the people are able to create categories for new items like in this example:

[Create category at runtime (German Inventar Program)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEl6v.png)

My problem here is that I use firebase as the backend and - of course - upload all the attributes for the stored items whereas every item belongs to a category with predefined attributes. When I want to work with these items, I download the item from firebase and create an object with these specific attributes from a class I hard-coded at compile time.

I don't want to hard code the class at compile time and change all the functions and if-else blocks where i am checking for the actual category for an item. Now - when adding a new category - I have to change at least 50 places in code to make it work...

For better understanding, here is a function for one category which downloads all the items from firebase:

```
func downloadMiscsFromFirebase(handler: @escaping (_ miscs: [Miscellaneous]) -> ()) {
    var miscs = [Miscellaneous]()
    DataService.instance.hardwareRef.child(category).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshots {
                let description = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: FirebaseIDs.Item.description).value as! String
                let category = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: FirebaseIDs.Item.category).value as! String
                let lfdNr = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: FirebaseIDs.Item.lfdNr).value as! Int
                let fromTeam = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: FirebaseIDs.Item.fromTeam).value as! String

                let hw = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: FirebaseIDs.Miscellaneous.hw).value as! String
                let sw = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: FirebaseIDs.Miscellaneous.sw).value as! String
                let other = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: FirebaseIDs.Miscellaneous.other).value as! String
                let givenOut = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: FirebaseIDs.Item.givenOut).value as? Bool
                let givenTo = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: FirebaseIDs.Item.givenTo).value as? String
                let givenAt = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: FirebaseIDs.Item.givenAt).value as? String
                let givenUntil = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: FirebaseIDs.Item.givenUntil).value as? String
                let storageLocation = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: FirebaseIDs.Item.storageLocation).value as? String

                let misc = Miscellaneous(UID: snap.key,
                                          lfdNr: lfdNr,
                                          description: description,
                                          category: category,
                                          fromTeam: fromTeam,
                                          hw: hw,
                                          sw: sw,
                                          other: other,
                                          givenOut: givenOut,
                                          givenTo: givenTo,
                                          givenAt: givenAt,
                                          givenUntil: givenUntil,
                                          storageLocation: storageLocation)

                // Only add item if from the same team.
                if fromTeam == self.fromTeam {
                    miscs.append(misc)
                }

            }
            handler(miscs)
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a general CategoryDefinition class/struct and a Category class/struct that looked something like

```
class CategoryDefinition {
    var categoryName: String
    var fields: [String: FieldType] //Dictionary with field definitions
}

class Category {
    var values: [String: Any?] //Dictionary with field values
}
```

then two functions to convert from and to Firebase format.

To make it more flexible to work with this I would have a protocol with the properties and functions I mentioned. It would make sense to have a Factory class to generate Category instances from CategoryDefinition.

FieldType above is my made up enum since I assume you have pre-defined set of data types-

Comment: Thanks for your help!!